# "And introducing..." used for known actors?

Tags: credits

I have atleast 2 examples of well known established actors credited at the very end with the phrase "and introducing" before their name:

- Julia Roberts in *Ocean's Eleven* (2001) (in the end credits)
- Daniel Craig in *Logan Lucky* (2017) (on the posters at least; I haven't watched the movie yet*)

Coincidence: Both the mentioned movies are directed by Steven Soderbergh.

Is there a specific reason as to why this is done?

P.S. I have seen these kind of phrases attached in front of debutante actors multiple times. But that obviously isn't the case here.

Edit:
As pointed out in a comment by HorusKol, another example is for Rob Lowe in *Parks and Recreation*.

Edit 2: The list goes on.

- Cloris Leachman in *Raising Hope*.(Courtesy: Kevin Milner)
- Don Johnson in *Machete*.(Courtesy: Erics)
- Carlos Estevez(birth name) in *Machete Kills*.(Courtesy: Wikipedia, the website)

---

*: As confirmed by user Michael Seifert, Daniel Craig has an ''and introducing" credit in the movie as well.

Comment: Not limited to Soderbergh productions - Rob Lowe got an "and introducing" credit on _Parks and Recreation_ despite being a member of the 80s brat-pack.

Comment: @HorusKol I did say at least 2. And I haven't seen *Parks and Recreation*. So I'll add that in.

Comment: They did this pretty much the whole run of "Raising Hope" for Cloris Leachman.

Comment: I don't think the question needs to be edited to cover every well-known actor who's ever been given an "And introducing..." credit. It would end up being much too broad and in danger of being closed for lacking focus.

Comment: Jonathan Harris, who was a regular in the original _Lost in Space_ series, negotiated with Irwin Allen for the credit "guest starring" in (approximately) every episode.

Comment: I just watched *Logan Lucky* on video last weekend, and can confirm that Daniel Craig's credit is "And Introducing..." in the movie as well.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### These are joke credits deliberately placed by the director Stephen Soderbergh.

> **“Introducing” Julia Roberts**
>
> Soderbergh: She was the only person we had in mind. We thought it would be fun for her to be the only woman. We sent her the script with $20 enclosed and a note saying, “We hear you get 20 for a picture”.
>
> Clooney: She kept the 20. We deducted it from her wages. Actually, we deducted it from Andy’s salary.
>
> Soderbergh: **We thought it would be a scream to have the credits say, “Introducing Julia Roberts”. Her agent didn’t agree, but Julia thought it was hysterical.** I think the only people who would be concerned with something like that are people who are insecure
>
> [Source](http://www.bradpittpress.com/artint_02_totalfilm2.php)

Comment: Damn. What a cool interview

Comment: Strange, I've never thought of Julia Roberts as completely secure. Much like Sandra Bullock, when she is interviewed, she always seems (to me anyway) completely surprised that anyone would want to interview _her_.

Comment: Also, it would appear that Rob Lowe's introducing credit was [also a joke](https://www.vulture.com/2010/05/rob_lowe_parks_and_recreation.html)

Comment: @CGCampbell Seems like humility rather than insecurity.

Comment: hmmm, let's see, _Humility: a modest or low view of one's own importance; humbleness_, OK, now, _Insecurity: uncertainty or anxiety about oneself; lack of confidence_,  .... yes

Answer (score 12):

[Don Johnson in Machete](https://www.nbcbayarea.com/news/national-international/mystery-solved-why-don-johnson-received-introducing-credit-in-machete/1877601/)

> When Johnson agreed to come on board for "Machete," most of the specialized credits -- the "with" the "and" and the "featuring" which actors like to have so much --  were taken.
>
> It was particularly hard since Johnson was such a late addition to the film.
>
> "We were discussing it and (Johnson) said, 'why not introducing?' " Rodriguez tells us with a laugh. "I thought, 'Perfect.'"

Comment: _Machete_ also stars Carlos Estevez, a relatively unknown name with a rather famous face.

Comment: *Machete Kills* stars Carlos Estevez. And uses the same gimmick. Courtesy Wikipedia ;)

Comment: There's a old joke about five stages of actor name recognition; I've most often seen it applied to Ricardo Montalban, but it works here: "Stage 1. Who is Don Johnson? 2. Get me Don Johnson. 3. Get me a Don Johnson type. 4. Get me a young Don Johnson. 5. Who is Don Johnson?" I think part of the joke of "introducing" is that Johnson would be at stage 5 for viewers not old enough to have seen Miami Vice.

Comment: @Russell Borogove I'm sixteen so I haven't watched Miami Vice. **But** I'm a bit of a movie freak so I fall in stage 2 :P

Comment: Although the 2006 Miami Vice movie wasn't _tooo_ terrible, the 80's original series (starring Johnson) was for Miami what Magnum PI was for Hawaii... _THE_ 80's series to watch and dream about girls and bikinis and beaches and warm weather and .. girls

Comment: I knew him as Nash Bridges...!

Comment: The credit of Carlos Estevez is not entirely a joke. It is more tongue-in-cheek. It is the actor’s real name. His father is Ramón Estevez. Although, no one calls him that. So, the director has to “introduce” him as Carlos. After all, this is a Mexican movie franchise, from a Mexican producer/director, with mainly Mexican main characters and protagonists, with white bad guys. This intentionally/overtly puts Carlos in the position of good guy (for now).

Answer (score 1):

In *Another Time, Another Place* (1958) The 7th actor listed by IMDB was Martin Stephens (born July 15, 1959) as Brian Trevor.

One might expect that *Another Time, Another Place* might be the first movie role of someone who was eight or nine when it was made, but IMDB lists an earlier movie role for Martin Stephens.

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0827101/?ref_=tt_cl_t7[1](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0827101/?ref_=tt_cl_t7)

The fourth billed actor was Sean Connery (born August 25, 1930) as Mark Trevor.  *Another Time, Another Place* is listed as the 14th role of Sean Connery, so he seems to have been somewhat more experienced at the time than Martin Stephens.

https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000125/?ref_=tt_cl_t4[2](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000125/?ref_=tt_cl_t4)

But when I saw *Another Time, Another Place* on television I noticed that the credits included "Introducing Sean Connery".

> Though the opening credits say "Introducing Sean Connery", several movies, in which he appeared, were released before this one.

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051364/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv[3](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051364/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv)

So this is another rather whimsical use of "introducing".

Comment: A similar use was made for Scarlett Johansson,  in her 7th or 8th feature film, I can't seem to remember the name of the film.

Comment: Also, you got a typo-Martin Stephens was born in *1949*.